# Firebase - Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid au

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Hello I'm using firebase functions and I have created a Node.js project with `firebase init`, then I selected the options ***functions***, ***firebase*** and ***storage***. The project works with the `firebase-admin` NPM package.

When I deploy the project with `firebase deploy` everything goes well, but when I run the function on the cloud, it says the following message:

[image: Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential]

I have tested the entire project with the emulators and it works well.

Project Structure:

[image: Project structure]

What is causing this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was that I had this in the initializeApp:

```
const serviceAccount = require("../project-name-f3ad6ae0572f.json");
    
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  storageBucket: BUCKET_NAME,
});
```

This is incorrect because I was missing the firebase configuration that is given on the Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> Your Apps.

Then, the result has to be like this:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxx-your-api-key-xxx",
  authDomain: "project-name.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "project-name",
  storageBucket: "project-name.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  appId: "x:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:web:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  measurementId: "G-XXXXXXXXX",
};

admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are explicitly setting the configuration rather than using the default configuration?

Comment: Yes because the bucket was not working, but I figured out when I used the default configuration that it was working perfectly anyways

Comment: Also for future reference, if you need to override the defaults (which are passed in to the functions via a environment variable), you can use `const FIREBASE_CONFIG = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG); admin.initializeApp({...FIREBASE_CONFIG, ...{ /* overrides here */ }});`

Answer (score 1):

verify your pc time, i had same problem and  resolving  when update pc time.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
const serviceAccount = require('./firebase.json');

if (!admin.apps.length) {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  });
}

export const firebaseDB = admin.firestore();
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be late to this question but I faced a similar issue yesterday (16 October 2022). What I figured is that, when you set your computer's time manually, firebase doesn't work.

So your firebase timestamp rules must match with your current host time.

Answer (score 0):

The code for the function framework is actually public in the GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs repository (although not advertised anywhere).

In particular you can see there the cases where `killInstance` is used, which is the one triggering exit code 16:

```
const killInstance = process.exit.bind(process, 16);
```

These cases are (at the time of writing):

· [uncaughtException](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception)
· [unhandledRejection](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today, if it's only happening in your local environment, there's a 99% chance that your computer's time is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just got the same error and thanks to this thread, it helped point me in the right direction.  Problem solved for me. It was not date/time for me.
It was:

```js
const serviceAccount = require('your-app-name-firebase-adminsdk-rbtsc...JSON')
```

I generated a new private key and I'm back in the game.